# table with different partitions in athena aws

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, partition, amazon-athena, presto

Is it possible to create a table with different types of partitions in athena?

for example having a partition per year month day and another partition only by id

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_example(
        name string,  
        adress 
        PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string) ----> partition 1
        PARTITIONED BY (id int) -----------> partition 2

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
LOCATION 's3://example/folder/';
```

is something similar to this possible?

thanks

Comment: Not what you're asking but something similar -> Athena uses Apache Hive–style data partitioning.  You can partition your data across multiple dimensions―e.g., month, week, day, hour, or customer ID―or all of them together. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
Partitioning is not "indexing". It's layout of the data on the file system (or file-system-like storage, here: s3).
What you're after would be two independent copies of the data. For this, you can simply create two tables, one with partitioning by year/month/day and second with partitioning by id.

However, assuming that `id` is an identifier in your table, you really do not want to partition by `id`. You might be interested in exploring bucketing by id, though.